# Offline install of DBATools not working in PS 4.0

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I’m trying to do an offline install of DBATools to a 2012 server. The server is on PS V4.0. I’ve been able to install it on SQL 2016 servers. I downloaded the most recent version of DBATools to my desktop and then copied it to the Powershell modules folder. Any tips?

Comment: I doubt it supports version 4? Have you confirmed? Maybe an older version would be more ideal?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can use PS 4 if the DBATools folder is in the right format. But it appears that DBATools needs .net 4.6 and Windows 2012 uses 4.5 so upgrading Powershell is probably the best way to fix it.